# Unable to modify /etc/shells on macOS to include brew installed version of bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, homebrew

I am trying to update my `/etc/shells` file to include the path to a homebrew installed version of `bash` which resides at `/usr/local/bin/bash`

`$ sudo echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells` returns Permission denied and attempting to manually update is not allowed as it appears to be read-only.

Upon inspecting the file, the permissions are set as follows:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 179 Feb 21  2017 /etc/shells`

So, with this in mind, and after looking at this [article](https://johndjameson.com/blog/updating-your-shell-with-homebrew/) about *Updating you shell with Homebrew* I tried to initiate a shell as the root user and then try command above, i.e:

```
$ sudo -s
$ echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells
$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

However, this seems to hang on the first command (`$ sudo -s`). This spawns a `bash` process that eats up ~ 70% CPU and nothing happens.

Is there an alternative way one can update the `/etc/shells/` file?

Comment: An approach to adding to a root-only file is `echo /usr/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`. Although if `sudo -s` is causing issues, it implies that something else has messed up as it should not be churning with high cpu utilization.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @Petesh for the quick reply! That worked like a charm. If you post that as an answer I'll accept that as the answer. Would you be able to explain why that works and the `sudo echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells` does not though. I'm unsure as to _why_ your command works. Thanks again.

Comment: Questions about system configuration are not really suitable for Stack Overflow. Bash *programming* is fine but this seems to be squarely a general and very basic Unix admin question. Maybe familiarize yourself with [apple.se], [unix.se], and/or [su] for this type of question (but check out their guidelines, too, before posting -- in particular, look for duplicates).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> An approach to adding to a root-only file is `echo /usr/local/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`.
>                       – Petesh

---

> Would you be able to explain why that works and the `sudo echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells` does not though.

The latter doesn't work because the output redirection `>>` is (tried to be) applied by the shell *before* the `sudo …` is executed, and of course the user shell has no permission to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just use this (I had to do this on macOS Mojave):

```
sudo sh -c "echo $(which zsh) >> /etc/shells"
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```